# Integrating Swift Custom framework with Cordova plugin

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have integrated my swift custom framework in my sample cordova application as a cordova plugin(created as a swift cordova plugin).
All I can achieve is, only importing framework module in plugin's swift wrapper file.

I cannot able to access the any of the public methods or other classes inside the custom framework.

Kindly guide me in spotting where am going wrong/missing something.

Please share any tutorials/samples of the cordova application with the swift framework(cordova-plugin)

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code how you are defining class and methods in your swift class so we can guide you on basis of swift code.

Comment: The class that I expose is defined in this format:
@objc public class XXXX: NSObject

Comment: try to replace public with open keyword it will expose your class out side your current module.

Comment: The public method inside the class is defined in this format:
@objc public class func YYYYY()

Comment: Even after defining it as open, my swift class is not recognised by the compiler in the cordova app. Even while importing the Framework module, it does not help me with auto-complete feature. I literally typed the Framework module name while importing.
On jumping to the definition of the Framework, I can only see:
public var ZZZZZVersionNumber: Double - property declaration. @CodeChanger